# What is the correct way to fit sigma.formula in gamlss() to add a per-dependent variable variance?

Tags: variance, heteroscedasticity, negative-binomial-distribution, gamlss

I have data in the format:

```
 | organism | treatment | replicate | response |
 | ---      | ---       | ---       | ---      |
 | A        | X         | 1         | 20       |
 | A        | X         | 2         | 5        |
 | A        | Y         | 1         | 10       |
 | A        | Y         | 2         | 12       |
 | A        | Z         | 1         | 8        |
 | A        | Z         | 2         | 6        |
 | B        | X         | 1         | 20       |
 | B        | X         | 2         | 5        |
 | B        | Y         | 1         | 10       |
 | B        | Y         | 2         | 12       |
 | B        | Z         | 1         | 8        |
 | B        | Z         | 2         | 6        |
```

Where 'organism', 'treatment', and replicate are all categorical variables.
There is also a 'length' variable which represents the exposure rate for each
organism. The 'response' variable appears to follow a negative binomial
distribution, where the variance is not equal to the mean. I have previous
modelled this data using a multilevel model where 'organism' is the random
effect:

```
glmer.nb(response ~ treatment + (1|organism) + offset(log(length)) - 1, data = ...)
```

I removed the intercept in the model, because it is uninterpretable to have an
expected response with no organism or treatment.

This model however has large amounts of heteroscedasticity where the fitted
versus standard residuals shows an obvious trend. Checking with dharma also
indicates overdispersion in the residuals (if this is the correct way to
describe the two-sided uniform test outlined in the dharma manual?). Plotting
residuals versus treatment shows differing amounts of residual variance for
each treatment, suggesting that variance should also be modelled based on the
dependent variable.

I have followed up with the gamlss package and fit a model with
dependent-variable specific variance as:

```
gamlss(formula       = response ~ treatment + random(organism) + offset(log(length)) - 1,
       sigma.formula = ~ organism + treatment,
       data = ...)
```

Comparing `sigma.formula = ~ 1` and `sigma.formula = ~ organism + treatment`
models using BIC suggests I should accept the latter model as being more
parsimonious. The heteroscedasticity has also disappeared, where there residual
versus fitted plot now appears normally distributed along the y-axis 0.

Is this the correct way to fit variance as a dependent variable in a model?
I've only had previous experience with glms and mixed effect models, so I don't
have intuition about what seems sensible when using gamlss.

Comment: Hello, have you come to a conclusion regarding your question? I'm having the same kind of problem and I took the same direction (using gamlss with other types of distribution and trying to model sigma as a function of some predictor...) I'm wondering however, if modelling sigma as a function of your predictors is really a legit way of modelling the variance of a response variable as a function of these predictors as well?

@Isabella Ghement, this question seems right up your alley!